# membase - memcache 1.7.1.1 - windows - change the maximum item size limit

Tags: caching, memory, memcached, limit

I would like to know how to change the limit on an item that is cached in memcache 1.7.1.1.  This is not the quota size for the node or cluster but rather the limit on a single cached item.  This limit, from what I have read, is set to 1 MB.

I have content which is larger than the 1 MB per item limit and I would like to increase it to something higher.

I have read of a configuration parameter to "membase.exe", the "-I" parameter.  But I cannot seem to find it.

I really do not want to go down the road of recompiling with my own limit coded in.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is really only half an answer, but have you considered just using a membase bucket instead? You'll get a 20 MB limit with no config changes necessary.